# Data Hiding in Python Class

Tags: python

I know that the attributes of class which are declared by double underscore `__` prefix may or may not visible outside the class definition. As we can still access those attributes by `object._className__attrName`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        ----
        ----
        self.z = 26
        self.catch = 100
```

Now to protect all attributes except the attribute `catch`, I have to declare them with double underscore which is quite messy. Is there a way I can say in my class definition that only `self.catch` can be accessed outside the class?

Apologies if this is answered somewhere else or discussed earlier.

Comment: No. However, unless you're really paranoid, the fact that someone *can* access an object using `object._className__attrName` isn't a big deal. You really just want to prevent people from accidentally accessing variables they shouldn't when using your code. The obfuscation achieves that goal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does python have 'private' variables in classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes)

Comment: @BjörnPollex, this isn't what he's asking for. He wants the need for an explicit "public" "operator", not the opposite.

Comment: Do you really need double underscore? Why not just use the more standard single underscore `self._a`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to hide private data in a closure -- at least, if there is a way to access `private` from outside `make_A`, I haven't found it:

```
def make_A():
    private = {
        'a' : 1,
        'b' : 2,
        'z' : 26,
        }
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.catch = 100
            private['a'] = 2    # you can modify the private data
        def foo(self):
            print(private['a']) # you can access the private data 
    return A

A = make_A()

a=A()

a.foo()
# 2
```

Notice that `private` is not in `dir(a)`

```
print('private' in dir(a))
# False
```

Although this is possible, I do not think this is recommendable way to program in Python.

---

Above, `private` is shared by all instances of `A`. To use private data on a per-instance basis, add `self` to the dict key:

```
def make_A():
    private = {}
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.catch = 100
            private[self,'a'] = 1    # you can modify the private data
            private[self,'b'] = 2    
            private[self,'z'] = 26    
        def foo(self):
            print(private[self,'a']) # you can access the private data 
    return A
```

Comment: Thumbs up for ***closures**. This may be of interest: [Secret Variables i Python](http://www.jotflow.com/jot/Secret-Variables-In-Python/5). It compares functional data hiding in Python with private variables in Java.

Comment: Looks good, but it will lead to memory leak, because once an instance of `A` is created, it will be always referenced by the dict `private`. Python cannot GC it until the `private` is GC'ed.

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer by `unutbu` looks like a good idea to hide data, the `private` dictionary still accessible using `__closure__` (this attribute cannot be removed):

```
def make_A():
    private = {}
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.catch = 100
            private[self,'a'] = 1    # you can modify the private data
            private[self,'b'] = 2    
            private[self,'z'] = 26    
        def foo(self):
            print(private[self,'a']) # you can access the private data
    return A


A = make_A()
a = A()
a.foo()  # 1
a.foo.__closure__[0].cell_contents[(a, 'a')] = 42
a.foo()  # 42
```

Or following the link provided by `Sumukh Barve` in the comments:

```
def createBankAccount():
    private = {'balance': 0.0}
    def incr(delta):
        private['balance'] += delta;
    account = {
        'deposit': lambda amount: incr(amount),
        'withdraw': lambda amount: incr(-amount),
        'transferTo': lambda otherAccount, amount: (
            account['withdraw'](amount),
            otherAccount['deposit'](amount)
        ),
        'transferFrom': lambda otherAccount, amount: (
            otherAccount['transferTo'](account, amount)
        ),
        'getBalance': lambda : private['balance']
    }
    return account;


account = createBankAccount()

print(account['getBalance']())
account['getBalance'].__closure__[0].cell_contents['balance'] = 1000**1000
print(account['getBalance']())  # I can buy a couple of nations
```

I bevile the only way to create **`private`** attributes is to write some kind of `CPython` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, since it's part of the name, you can't do that.

Well, actually you can through hacking with the getters/setters, but you generally shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

*Why* might you want to protect attributes?

If you want to protect attributes from inadvertent overwriting, use double underscores and, probably, ready-only properties to make access easier. But most of the time, [you aint't gonna need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it). Just do yourself a favor and leave the attributes open, this makes debugging far easier.

If you want to protect your object from tampering by third parties, you can play with `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, but probably you should not pass to an untrusted client objects with protected data at all, use the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) instead and hide your valuables more opaquely. You might want to rethink your architecture, too.

Comment: *Why might you want to protect attributes?*

I could just point you to the wiki entry on encapsulation, but I will give you a practical example.  

Let's say you have a large and complex python application in which you have a number of classes with the attribute 'name'.  A bug is found in which the class administrator's name is being incorrectly overridden.  If you have left the name attribute open as you suggest, how will you find the offending line of code?  If you have hidden the attribute and used accessors, you can put a breakpoint on the getter and find the culprit fast.

Comment: @dar512: if your class is a part of a public interface, and clients might tamper with attributes, by all means guard them by accessors! The number of public classes is rather limited in a typical application, though. Also, using immutable data has numerous advantages; I often use subclasses of `namedtuple` to represent data in a bullet-proof way.

Comment: As a programmer, if I chose to shoot off my own leg with a shotgun, so be it. You are limiting my ability to fix / alter your code by hiding things. The 'protected' and 'private' keywords are just anti-patterns. Please abandon the notion that you are doing anyone a favour by 'hiding' things from other programmers. If you want to do something like this, use `_variable` and provide a `variable` getter property and no setter. I can still manually modify the `_variable` this way if I so wish. But do not use language hacks to obfuscate your internals from other programmers.