# how to change attribute of parent class

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes. In the object oriented methodology, I can change parent attribute from low level class. In python, how can I change variable of the parents from other class ? What I have

```
class Concurrent( threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
         self.rec = Rec()
         self.rec.start()
         self.parentvar = None # I have change this variable
         self.secondParentVar = [] # or use this

class Rec(Concurrent):
    def run(self):
        # from here, change variable of the parent Conccurent class variable
```

Comment: What parent variable are you trying to change?

Comment: so you want to change `self.rec = Rec()` or what?

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee I have not put any variable name. If you want `parentVar = None `

Comment: @user2396467 Does this code run?  I can't seem to get the class definitions to work.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee why do I need to give all code ? It is working.

Comment: @user2396467 your current code doesn't work since `Rec()` calls `Rec.__init__` which is inherited from `Concurrent.__init__`, which conveniently calls `Rec()`

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Do not bother with whether code is running or not. Last time, I know how to create a class.

Comment: SO favors working example code.

Comment: @user2396467 Generally the policy on SO is for the OP to include a http://sscce.org/ SSCCE.

Comment: In Python you can change anything from anywhere. What have you tried?

Comment: @LennartRegebro After I have started the rec instance, I have tried to change the concurrent instance variable. I have put print statement in concurrent instance but print only shows first initialized value such as none.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, and we won't know what until you actually include examples of *what you have tried*.

Comment: @lennart-regebro but it should be mentioned that you don't necessarily always want to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641236/1514681

Answer (score 2):

i think something like this would work:

```
class Concurrent( threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rec = Rec()
        self.rec.start()
        self.parentvar = None 

class Rec(Concurrent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self.parentvar = #new variable
        self.secondParentVar = [list1, list2]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this:

```
class Rec(Concurrent):
    def run(self):
        self.parentvar = "new value"
```