# NameError on imported class

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get rid of this `NameError`?

`main.py`

```
from com.domain.model import Employee

e1 = Employee("")
```

---

`model.py`

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,fname):
        setfname(fname)
    def setfname(fname): self._fname = fname

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self,fname): super(Employee,self).__init__(fname)
```

---

> `NameError: global name 'setfname' is not defined`

---

`main.py`

`com/`

--`domain/`

----`model.py`

Comment: Python is not Java...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qualify `setfname` as `self.setfname`. In addition to that, the instance method `setfname` should have `self` as the first parameter.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.setfname(fname)
    #   ^^^^^
    def setfname(self, fname):
    #            ^^^^^^
        self._fname = fname
```

Comment: Is it posb'l to create functions that are for personal use of a class?

Comment: @GLES, I don't understand the **personal use of a class**? Do you mean private method?

Comment: @GLES, See [Does python have 'private' variables in classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes) if you mean private method.