# How to return a mutable attribute as an immutable object?

Tags: python, collections, immutability

Is there a way to return a mutable attribute but protect it from updates?

I have a `Calendar` class that uses an internal `dict` instance mapping `datetime.date` instances to `list` instances of event identifiers:

```
class Calendar:

    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = {}
        
    def add_event(self, date, event):
        if date in self._dict:
            self._dict[date].append(event.id)
        else:
            self._dict[date] = [event.id]
            
    def get_event_ids(self, date):
        if date in self._dict:
            return self._dict[date]
        else:
            return []
```

I would like to protect the calendar from these updates:

```
calendar = Calendar()
calendar.add_event(date, event)
event_ids = calendar.get_event_ids(date)
event_ids[0] = 42  # updates the mutable list in the calendar
```

The rationale is that a user might want to update the list of event identifiers returned by the calendar, but he does not expect that doing so will update the calendar.

A read-only `property` doesn’t prevent a user from updating the lists.

A solution seems to return copies of the lists. But:

1. The `list` instances may become big and the `Calendar.get_event_ids` function may be called many times so performing a copy at each call can become inefficient.
2. In case a user actually wants to change the calendar, returning a copy will mislead him to think he can, because no exception is raised from updates to the `list` instances.
3. I think a user should be the one deciding to make a copy if he needs to do so.
4. I want to know if there is any other way to achieve the same thing.

Another possibility would be to return instances of my own `ImmutableList` class. It solves 2 and 3, but not 1 (because I will have to copy the `list` instances to initialize `ImmutableList` instances) neither 4. Also, it seems like too much work for a very simple concern.

I also know that ‘We are all consenting adults’ and that overprotecting my instance attributes is not Pythonic. But I think my curiosity got the better of me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?  You say you don't want to return a copy because the user might want to modify it, but you also don't want to return the real thing because then the user might modify it.  You can't have it both ways.  Either you return something that the user can modify (and affect the underlying data), or you don't.

Comment: You could return iterator instead of the list itself.

Comment: If you want an immutable collection then *use* an immutable connection (e.g. a `tuple`). Just modify `get_event_ids` to `return tuple(self._dict[date])`. By the way: you should really use a [`defaultdict(list)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) in your case and avoid, which lets you avoid all the `if`s.

Comment: Your English is definitely above average for SO, IMHO. :)

Comment: @Bakuriu But creating a new tuple from the list does not take the same time (or more) than copying it? Anyway, thank you for the `defaultdict` tip!

Comment: @BrenBarn I'd like something like returning a 'const vector<int> *' in C or C++. Something like aquavitae said.

Comment: @Laski That's what `tuple` does. It takes the same time to build as a list but is immutable. The only way to avoid copying is to use a view (like the answer you accepted, although I believe it could be improved. For example it would be better to use a `defaultdict(list)`, modify `PrivateList` so that it accepts the `list` in `__init__` and change `get_event_ids` to return `PrivateList(self._dict[date])`. In this way you reduce the overhead of creating tons of view and having to access private attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to create an immutable list which solves all your problems:

```
import collections.abc


class ImmutableList(collections.abc.Sequence):

    def __init__(self):
        self._list = []

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._list[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)


class Calendar:

    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = collections.defaultdict(ImmutableList)

    def add_event(self, date, event):
        self._dict[date]._list.append(event.id)

    def get_event_ids(self, date):
        return self._dict[date]
```

`ImmutableList` exposes a tuple-like API so a user won’t accidentally change something, but has a private `_list` attribute which `Calendar` can access to manipulate the data. Note that the leading underscore is just a convention and doesn’  actually enforce private scope in the way that a language like C++ would.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes) is a question which explains the scoping a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

> Another possibility would be to return instances of my own `ImmutableList` class. It solves 2 and 3, but not 1 (because I will have to copy the `list` instances to initialize `ImmutableList` instances) neither 4.

If you returned an immutable `tuple` instance from a mutable `list` instance it would perform a shallow copy (e.g. `tuple([1, 2, 3])`), but if you return your own `ImmutableList` instance you don’t have to perform *any* copy at initialization since you can store a *reference* to the mutable `list` instance. `ImmutableList` will be a [protection proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) providing a read-only dynamic view on the mutable `list` instance (i.e. you cannot update the mutable `list` instance from the `ImmutableList` instance but changes to the mutable `list` instance will reflect in the `ImmutableList` instance):

```py
import collections.abc
import datetime

class Event:
    def __init__(self, id_):
        self._id = id_
    def get_id(self):
        return self._id

class ImmutableList(collections.abc.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, list_):
        self._list = list_
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._list[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)

class Calendar:
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    def add_event(self, date, event):
        self._dict[date].append(event.get_id())
    def get_event_ids(self, date):
        return ImmutableList(self._dict[date])
```

```
>>> c = Calendar()
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> c.add_event(d, Event('birthday'))
>>> l = c.get_event_ids(d)
>>> del l[0]  # read-only view
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'ImmutableList' object doesn't support item deletion
>>> list(l)
['birthday']
>>> c.add_event(d, Event('christmas'))
>>> list(l)  # dynamic view
['birthday', 'christmas']
```

Note that in this solution, the `Calendar` class stores and updates the mutable `list` instances directly and only wraps them in `ImmutableList` instances when returned from the `Calendar.get_event_ids` function. It differs from [@aquavitae’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21427622/2326961) where the `Calendar` class stores and updates the mutable `list` instances from `ImmutableList` instances by accessing their *internal* attributes, thereby coupling the `ImmutableList` class with the `Calendar` class, which compromises [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) (also known as encapsulation).