# Underscore on both sides of word in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what does this mean?

```
Order.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
```

Is that a method? What's different about it when it has the underscore on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a method. There's nothing intrinsically special about it in Ruby; it's kind of a [Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes) way of indicating a method/attribute that's internal to the `Order` object and shouldn't be messed with. It also reduces the chances that someone will overwrite it by accident.

Comment: Fyi, for languages other than Python the term is "idiomatic". Or were you specifically trying to say that this is something idiomatic in Python?

Comment: @Ajedi32 It's a common Python practice, but certainly not idiomatic Ruby (`__send__` notwithstanding).