# Python class is using instantiated values even after updating

Tags: python, class

I am running the following code:

```
class testClass:
    def __init__(self, left, width):
        self.__left = left
        self.__width = width

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.__left

    @left.setter
    def left(self, newValue):
        self.__left = newValue

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.__width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, newValue):
        self.__width = newValue

    def right(self):
        return self.__width + self.__left

    def rightFixed(self):
        return self.width + self.left

test = testClass(10,5)
test.left = 50
print test.right()
print test.rightFixed()
```

I am getting the values

```
15
55
```

Can anyone explain why the first method test.right() is giving the value 15, whereas if I call the test.rightFixed() value it gives me the appropriate value? I have looked in the interpreter, and _testClass__left after the code has run gives me 10, whereas it should give me 50. The @left.setter property doesn't seem to be updating the self.__left, rather it seems to be making it's own copy.

EDIT: I should also note, I am running 2.7.6. As Games Brainiac pointed out, this works fine in python 3+.

Comment: I'm getting 55, 55. Using python 3 tho.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using 2.7.

Comment: Why are you using double underscores?

Comment: @mattm Yea, if he does that then it gets added as class attrs.

Comment: This is part of a group project. The member who wrote the code that is causing this issue wants to do encapsulation. I told him it's not the way it's normally done, but he comes from a world of Fortran and C++. He is dead set on private variables.

Comment: Well if it's a private variable you shouldn't be doing `test.__left` anyway.

Comment: @ixwt `_var` is set to private mate, not `__var`

Comment: @ixwt: double underscore isn't private, it's superprivate, and pretty unpythonic. You're teammate is in a world of hurt if he is going to try to write Python as if it were C++.

Comment: Off topic to the original question, but: Just because you're used to another language doesn't mean you should try to force that languages practices on another. There's a reason `from __future__ import braces` acts the way it does. Tell your friend to deal with it.

Comment: @mattm I told him about the naming convention, and I was using [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes) and [This reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) document which both say that double underscore is private.

Comment: Reject any of his code containing self.__var... Point him to those references or here.

Comment: Unless you're trying to "avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses", using `__` is nine kinds of silly, and ugly to boot.

Comment: @ixwt: Double underscore is technically private, it's just not the pythonic way to do private variables. Static languages have public/private keywords, and the double underscore is close to that in Python, but it goes against what Python is about. A single underscore is  a naming convention in Python to indicate to the programmer that it's a private variable.

Comment: @mattm. I just looked it up in PEP8. It seems you're mostly right. Double underscore should only be used in the case that you don't want an inheriting class to mess with values, which doing it this way is still unpythonic in a sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `(object)` to your class. After Python 2.6 a new data model was introduced. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle.

See the comments by DSM for why Python3 and Python2 treat it different.

```
class testClass(object):
    def __init__(self, left, width):
        self.__left = left
        self.__width = width

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.__left

    @left.setter
    def left(self, newValue):
        self.__left = newValue

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.__width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, newValue):
        self.__width = newValue

    def right(self):
        return self.__width + self.__left

    def rightFixed(self):
        return self.width + self.left

>>test = testClass(10,5)
>>test.left = 50
>>print test.right()
55
>>print test.rightFixed()
55
```

Comment: This seems to fix the problem. Although I am curious as to why.

Comment: This solves the problem because you need to be a new-style class to have descriptor support, and properties are descriptors.  "(Note that descriptors are only invoked for new style objects or classes (a class is new style if it inherits from object or type)."  See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) for more than you care to know.

Comment: In Python 3, all classes are 'new-style' classes.

Comment: @DSM Not really. `property` is lazy by default in py2, its not in py3.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: ?  `property` doesn't apply to old-style classes.

Comment: @DSM It does. Even in the docs, properties are used, without inheriting from object.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: take an example from the docs, say the last one in [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) of the docs, and add `print "setter was called"` to the setter method.  Instantiate it, type `a.x = 2`, and watch "setter was called" be printed.  Then remove `object`, and try it again.

Comment: @DSM Will do. I think its not exactly lazy, but something else.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: `property` is not designed to work with old-style classes. I've noticed in particular that `__set__()` never gets called. From the [python documentation on descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=property#invoking-descriptors): "descriptors only work for new style objects and classes". This fact is repeated several times on the descriptor documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

Because Python will 'name-mangle' double underscores. If you must use double underscores, then when you access them you have to do it as follows:

`test._testClass__left`

But instead you should just use a single underscore, which indicates a private variable, and you can continue on normally.

Comment: This isn't the issue here, though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue. And besides, won't all the values be mangled? A single underscore still gives me an incorrect value.

Comment: Ah, yes, @Parker got to it, I didn't even notice he forgot to inherit from `object`