# How to declare a static attribute in Python?

Tags: python, class, static, attributes

How can I declare a static attribute in Python?

Here is written how I can declare a method: 
[Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Comment: What are you calling "static" exactly ? The definition is very different from language to language. And even in the same language depending on where it's declared (like in C/C++, static at file level, static at function level or static at class level, 3 completely different thing...)

Comment: I have a class and I want all the objects to have by default a static attribute. In C++ you can write: `static int statischeVariable=5;`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

All variables defined on the class level in Python are considered static

```
class Example:
    Variable = 2           # static variable

print Example.Variable     # prints 2   (static variable)

# Access through an instance
instance = Example()
print instance.Variable    # still 2  (ordinary variable)


# Change within an instance 
instance.Variable = 3      #(ordinary variable)
print instance.Variable    # 3   (ordinary variable)
print Example.Variable     # 2   (static variable)


# Change through Class 
Example.Variable = 5       #(static variable)
print instance.Variable    # 3  (ordinary variable)
print Example.Variable     # 5  (static variable)
```

You can have two different variables in your class under the same name (one static and one ordinary).
Don't be confused.

Comment: this is a class variable, and has different behavior than e.g. `@staticmethod`.  The only answer I see that correctly identifies the difference between class attributes and staticattributes is the downvoted one (!)

Answer (score 21):

Just to add to it, you can have static variables in functions as well, not only classes:

```
def some_fun():
    some_fun.i += 1
    print(some_fun.i)

some_fun.i = 0;
print(some_fun(), some_fun(), some_fun())  
# prints: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 13):

All variables declared inside the Class' body are 'static' attributes.

```
class SomeClass:
    # this is a class attribute
    some_attr = 1

    def __init__(self):
        # this is an instance attribute
        self.new_attr = 2
```

But keep in mind that the 'static' part is by convention, not imposed (for more details on this, read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes)).

For more details of this convention and its implications, here is a quick excerpt from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references):

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from
>   inside an object, don’t exist in Python. However, there is a
>   convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with
>   an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of
>   the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It
>   should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change
>   without notice.
>
> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to
>   avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there
>   is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any
>   identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at
>   most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.

Answer (score 2):

static attributes are [data attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) in python.
so that attributes assigned in class:-

```
>>>class A(object):
>>>    a = 1

>>>A.a
>>>1
```

This is different from C++ and Java,  where a static member can't be accessed using an instance:-

```
>>>inst  = A()
>>>inst.a
1
>>>
```

also builtin method `setattr` will help you to set `static variable(data attribute)`.

```
>>>setattr(A, 'b', 2)
>>>A.b
>>>inst.b
```

Comment: The statement, "This is different from C++ and Java, where a static member can't be accessed using an instance" is completely incorrect.  See https://ideone.com/ndh37g for an example.  I think you may have accidentally switched the order in your statement, because the converse that "in C++ and Java, and instance member can't be accessed using a class" is true.

Answer (score 0):

From those that come here to use `setattr` as a means of adding static method to class, you need `staticmethod` function.

```py
def func_c():
    return 1

class A:
    pass

setattr(A, 'f', staticmethod(func_c))
a_instance = A()
a_instance.f()
```

---

Rationale

If it is your class, it is easier to write it like this:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def func_c():
    return 1
```

But, that is not always the case.

Since default setattr when passing function changes to `classmethod`, this will throw `TypeError: func_c() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

```py
def func_c():
    return 1

class A:
    pass

setattr(A, 'f', func_c)
a_instance = A()
a_instance.f()
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use standard @property decorator to make static attribute:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def a(self):
        return 1

a = A()
print a.a

1

a.a = 2

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: What you doing is not a static attribut, it's a constant/read-only attribut.