# can anyone please explain me this piece of code

Tags: python-3.x

I know this is a noob question but I am learning OOPs and can't able to figure the outputs got

This is the code I found and may i know how this runs?

```
class InstanceCounter(object):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        InstanceCounter.count += 1

    def set_val(self, newval):
        self.val = newval

    def get_val(self):
        print(self.val)

    def get_count(self):
        print(InstanceCounter.count)

a = InstanceCounter(5)
b = InstanceCounter(10)
c = InstanceCounter(15)

for obj in (a, b, c):
    print("value of obj: %s" % obj.get_val())
    print("Count : %s" % obj.get_count())
```

Comment: I'm guessing you get the output 5, 3, 10, 3, 15, 3 ?

Comment: Yeah it's correct but may I know how we get that please

Comment: May i know why we get 3 after 5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a class called `InstanceCounter` which inherits from `object`. The inherince from  `object` can be [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object) if you use `Python3`. This class has an attribute `count` and `value` and some `methods` (functions - for example `set_val`).

Now you create three objects of your class and set the value of `value` to `5`, `10` and `15` by passing these values into the constructor. You also increase the **static** attribute (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481116/how-to-declare-a-static-attribute-in-python/27481965)) `count` by one with each constructor call. A static attribute is used with the notation `Class.Attribute`.

In the last step you loop over a list of your three objects (`(a, b, c)`) and store each of this object in the object `obj`, so `obj` will represent `a` then `b` and then `c`. So you can call the methods of this object, because your object `obj` has the type `InstanceCounter` and so `obj` contain the same methods and attributes.

By the way I have reworked your code so make it more understandable and use `Python3` syntax.

```
class InstanceCounter:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        InstanceCounter.count += 1

    def set_val(self, newval):
        self.val = newval

    def get_val(self):
        return self.val

    def get_count(self):
        return InstanceCounter.count

a = InstanceCounter(5)
print("Count : {}".format(a.get_count()))
b = InstanceCounter(10)
print("Count : {}".format(b.get_count()))
c = InstanceCounter(15)
print("Count : {}".format(c.get_count()))

for obj in (a, b, c):
    print("value of obj: {}".format(obj.get_val()))
    print("Count : {}".format(obj.get_count()))
```

This result in the following output:

```
Count : 1
Count : 2
Count : 3
value of obj: 5
Count : 3
value of obj: 10
Count : 3
value of obj: 15
Count : 3
```

For a better understanding of static attributes:

So if you have three objects with type `InstanceCounter` you have **three  different** attributes with name `val` because each object with type `InstanceCounter` contains one attribute `val` - an `instance attribute` and **one identical** attribute with name `count` - a `class attribute`.

- `count` is a `class attribute` for the class `InstanceCounter`. This
  attribute has the same value for all objects with type
  `InstanceCounter`. Used with `Classname.Attributename` - for example `InstanceCounter.count`.
- `val` is a `instance attribute` because each *instance*  of a class `InstanceCounter` has his own value. Used with `Instancename.Attributename` - for example `a.val`.

See [here](https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes) for more information.

Comment: I understood a bit but i have a silly doubt for value of obj 5 why the count is 3 and is same for all values?

Comment: Is that we have 3 objects and so obj.get_count() is 3??

Comment: I update my text to clarify this issue. Hope it helps better now.