# Python static attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-variables

I have the following code in Python 3:

```
class x():
    var = 0

x1 = x()
x2 = x()
print(x.var) #0
print(x1.var) #0
print(x2.var) #0
```

But if I change the attribute `var` for one instance, it change only for this instance:

```
x1.var = 1
print(x.var) #0
print(x1.var) #1
print(x2.var) #0
```

I would like the result to be:

```
x1.var = 1
print(x.var) #1
print(x1.var) #1
print(x2.var) #1
```

Comment: If you want to alter the class variable `x.var`, use `x.var = 1`.

Comment: You may have a look at this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481116/how-to-declare-a-static-attribute-in-python)

Comment: If you want `x1.var = ...` to change a *class* attribute, you'll need to define a [setter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that explicitly sets the *class* attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance attribute can shadow a class attribute of the same name. If you want to change a *class* attribute via an instance, you have to do so explicitly, by getting a reference to the class. Otherwise, you are just creating a new instance attribute, rather than updating the class attribute.

```
class X:
    var = 0

x1 = X()
x2 = X()
type(x1).var = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comment of @khelwood, you can change the class attribute by referencing `instance.__class__`:

```py
class x():
    var = 0

x1 = x()
x2 = x()
print(x.var) #0
print(x1.var) #0
print(x2.var) #0

x1.__class__.var = 1
print(x.var) #1
print(x1.var) #1
print(x2.var) #1
```

Comment: This will not change any `var` already set `x2.var = 10` would not be overwritten by `x1.__class__.var = 4`

Comment: Good to know, thanks @Igoranze