# What's the difference between self.__x and self.x

Tags: python, oop

I an trying to learn Python and I have a question. What's the difference between:

```
class A:

def __init__(self, name=""):
    self.name = name
```

and

```
class A:

def __init__(self, name=""):
    self.__name = name
```

I noticed that if I use the second option I get errors, but If I want to make getters and setter for my class, I need to use the "__name" form

Comment: __attr are private attributes

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes)

Comment: You can get several useful results by pasting your question's title into a Google search. Please do some independent research before asking a new question.