# How do I access a private static variable of one class from a method present in another class in python?

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
       self.name="XYZ"
    def collect_data(self):
        b=B.age 
        print(b)

class B:
    age=9

objectA=A()
objectA.collect_data()
```

Please tell me if this the correct way of accessing the static variable present in class "B" from class "A" . Also I would like to know had there been a static method in class "B" , would I be able to access that in any way from class A .

Comment: Python has no "static variable" - `B.age` here is a class attribute.

Comment: What Bruno said. `B.age` is neither private nor static.

Comment: are we saying that B.age cant be private ?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the static variable as you do is correct and you do access static methods in a similar way, I've updated your example code to do this below.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
       self.name="XYZ"
    def collect_data(self):
        b=B.age 
        print(b)
        B.static_method_b(10)

class B:
    age=9

    @staticmethod
    def static_method_b(val):
        print(val)

objectA=A()
objectA.collect_data()
```

Comment: Hey thanks Luke ! just one more question . Can this static variable be private ? suppose in Class B , it is __age=9 . Then how do I get to access from class A ? is it like B.__age=9 ?

Comment: @AnkitBiswas that is a bit more complicated, but someone has already explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes)