# add an attribute to an object in python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.n = name
        self.__a = age
lucy=Dog("lucy",2)
print(lucy.__a)

jack=Dog("jack",3)
jack.__a=10
print(jack.__a)
```

When I run it, `print(lucy.__a)` gives me an error, which is understandable, because `__a` is a private instance variable. What confuses me a bit is that, `print(jack.__a)` works perfectly fine. I think it's because we have the `jack.__a=10` before it. Could anyone explain to me exactly what is going on?

Comment: This discussion may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes

Comment: If you read up on the Python documentation for [Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), you'll see this line: "This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, **as long as it occurs within the definition of a class**."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining the results of `dir(jack)` shows what is going on:

```
['_Dog__a', '__a', ...]
```

Assigning the `__a` attribute from within the class invokes name mangling; the value is stored against `_Dog__a`. But assigning it from outside does not invoke that, so a *separate* value is stored on the instance as `__a`. So you can do:

```
>>> jack._Dog__a
3
>>> jack.__a
10
```