# Make an attribute private if needed to be accessed outside the class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, attributes

I am not very experienced in OOP in python, I was just wondering if I should make an attribute .__private  if I need to use it outside the class (Use it by creating a getter method returning the attribute I need) or should I just keep those attributes .public

Comment: you could make it private and create getters and setters, or you could use `@property`. A good read about this topic https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Comment: It's hard to answer it without the specific example, both ways are possible. In general I would suggest not exposing the attributes at all, keep them private and have no getter.

Comment: Python doesn't *really* support private attributes.  The conventional use is prefixing the attributes with `_`s as you have done like `__private`, it'll be hidden from most auto-complete features.  But if you want to access `__private` from outside the class, nothing can stop you.  Read more on this relevant thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes

Comment: Based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering-se-previo) I think you should consider to ask this question on [Software Engineering SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I have python 3.4 and I think it is supporting the private attributes. E.g. class Human, with an attribute __name. If I do Human = Human() and then print(Human._name) It says Human has no attribute __name

Comment: you can get the mangled name out of the `__dict__`  and access it. its not private as in private its just mangled.  just read what @Idlehands posted.

Comment: @Peter when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)