# How to set a read-only @property in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I am just wondering how can I use read-only property and set initial values in `__init__`

I would like to have something like this:
Simply private (as much a `python` enables privacy) variable which is set in constructor.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
         self.value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.value
```

As far I know this is not possible (cannot set the value)?

Comment: [does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are 1st class citizens in python. You cant have two members in your class that are named exactly the same. Essentially your class already has a `self.value` of type `<class 'property'>` that your code tries to set to a  integer given as `value` which is forbidden - so this error pop up.

Circumvent it by:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
         self._value = value  # private backer

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value 

my_a = A(22)       # works, no error
print(my_a.value)  # 22
```

Comment: Single underscore `self._value` would be better choice here. The double underscore would invoke name mangling.

Comment: No, not really. That feature is intended for preventing name collisions in inheritance situations, the single underscore is the correct convention for "not public API".