# Is this accessing private variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How is `a(object of F class)` is printing the private variable?

```
    class F:
        def __init__(self):
            self.__y=5
    a=F()
    a.__y=10
    print(a.__y)
```

The output is `10`. I know that the new assignment updated the value of `a.__y`(or y?). But, I'm not able to understand how `y` is accessed outside the class. I tried printing IDs of both, they are different. Can someone provide better explanation for this?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641236/10418812

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-variables-python/

Comment: They're not private variables. The `_` is just the writer of the code saying " don't mess with this please". Python doesn't actually do anything to make it "private".

Comment: You're accessing a completely different attribute outside the class.