# Using variable from _init_

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is a section from my code. Basically, I want access to the value given in the entry box, which is a part of the def *init* ..Is there any way around this without using global variables? Also, it is set up this way so that this variable can be used throughout my program. Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApp(tk.Tk):

def test():
    a = __init__.test_entry.get()
    print(a)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    test_entry = tk.Entry(self)
    test_entry.pack()

    submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=MyApp.test)
    submit_button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way for an external function to access the local variables defined in a function.

There are several ways to solve the problem you have without that though. You could make the variables defined in `__init__` instance variables (attributes of `self`) and make sure your external function can access the right instance (perhaps in a global variable).

Or you could define a function within the `__init__` function. Such a closure can access the variables defined in an outer namespace without issue. In your specific instance, you could even make the closure a really small one, using `lambda` to call the "real" outer function with an argument:

```
class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def test(test_entry):
        a = test_entry.get()
        print(a)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        test_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        test_entry.pack()

        submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: MyApp.test(test_entry))
        submit_button.pack()
```

The expression `lambda: MyApp.test(test_entry)` defines an unnamed function that keeps hold of the `test_entry` defined in the namespace of the `__init__` method. When the lambda function is called, it passes that value on to the `test` function. You could also move the whole `test` definition into the `__init__` method, and so call it directly, without a `lambda`, but that is often ugly as it involves lots of deep indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand you correctly tbh

Have you considered using this instead?
`self.__test_entry = tk.Entry(self)`

Comment: This way the variable is private (not 100% correct, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes#1641236))

Comment: No, it isn't. Python *doesn't have private variables*. By *convention*, you should use a *single-underscore* for variables that are not part of the public API

Comment: I get an error __init__.test_entry.get() is not defined. After making changes you suggested I still get that error. I am trying to get access to the test_entry within _init_, but am failing horribly lol.

Comment: @monto Firstly, `__init__` is not defined in that scope. Second, even if it were and were referring to `MainApp.__init__`, the *local variables* are not accessible as attributes to the function. That would sort of defeat the purpose of local variables

Comment: @monto you would also need to change the line in test to     a = self.__test_entry.get()    also consider using only one underscore as juanpa.arrivillaga proposed

Comment: After doing this I get the error, "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: You also need to change to "def test(self):" and to "self.__test_entry.pack()" for this to work, please look at the python documentation and some tutorials about variable scope and objects in python