# Private Class Variables in Python?

Tags: python, class

I'd like to be able to extend a class without inheriting one of the class variables.

Given this scenario:

```py
class A:
    aliases=['a','ay']

class B(A):
    pass

print(B.aliases)
```

I would rather get an error that B has not defined the `aliases` variable rather than have `B` accidentally called `ay`.

One could imagine a solution where aliases becomes a member of the instantiated object (`self.aliases`) and is set in `__init__` but I really want to be able to access the aliases using the `cls` object rather than an instance of the class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes

Comment: Yes. I read that already. It did not answer this question.

Comment: Python just doesn't have the types of visibility restrictions that other languages do. (Also, what you do mean by "rather than have `B` accidentally called `ay`"?)

Comment: Since "ay" is an alias to A but would also be used for B in the above.

Comment: What's wrong with putting `aliases = []` in `B`?

Comment: Nothing. I just wanted to force the error in case someone forgot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python does not have REALY private attributes. But you can define it with a double underscore (`__`):

```
class A:
    __aliases=['a','ay']

class B(A):
    pass

print(B.__aliases) # yields AttributeError
```

But you still will be able to access it with:

```
print(B._A__aliases)
```

Comment: Oh. This is just what I was hoping for.

Comment: And *that* is the solution!

Comment: I didn't realize the "__" mangling worked for class variables.

Answer (score 2):

This is kindof a ganky work around but here you go:

```
class K:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mems = dir(self)

def defaultMembers():
    k = K()
    return(k.mems)

class A:
    aliases=['a','ay']

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        for k in set(dir(self))-set(defaultMembers()):
            print("removing "+k)
            setattr(self, k, None)

a = A()
b = B()
print(b.aliases)
#None
print(a.aliases)
#['a','ay']
```

I guess all you really need is the `setattr(self, "aliases", None)` still this results in a None and not a non-variable. Unfortunately calsses don't support deletion because I tried to use del first.

Comment: I think the point was to modify the behaviour when accessing `aliases` from the class object (B) not a class instance (b).

Comment: idk how he expects to work with class variables without instantiating them

Comment: I was hoping there was some simple workaround such as "__aliases" not getting copied on extension.

Comment: I'm thinking this answer should now be removed.  Thanks!