# How to call a derived class method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
         #base constructor implementation
         pass

    def __virt_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def public_method(self):
        self.__virt_method()

class B(A):
    def __init(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        #derived constructor implementation
        pass

    def __virt_method(self):
        #some usefull code here
        pass
```

I'm trying to use it like this, supposing that the overridden method to be called:

```
b = B()
b.public_method()
```

But instead I'm getting `NotImplementedError` (Am I doing something wrong or is it a Python (2?) problem? I know that Python 2 is deprecated and it is better to use Python 3, but for now I really have no choice.

Comment: It should be `self.__virt_method()`

Comment: yes, it is a typo in the question, it is indeed self.__virt_method(). Corrected.

Comment: It's the same in Python 2 and 3, I get the error.

Comment: Alright, but how to fix it then? I can't believe that is not possible in Python, that works fine for every modern language

Comment: it's because of the leading double-underscores. Why are you using them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). The `__virt_method` will be renamed by Python internally to `_A__virt_method` in the base class, and `_B__virt_method` in the derived class:

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

---

Rename the method to `_virt_method` (only one underscore) and it will work:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
         # base constructor implementation
         pass

    def _virt_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def public_method(self):
        self._virt_method()

class B(A):
    def __init(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        # derived constructor implementation
        pass

    def _virt_method(self):
        # some useful code here
        pass
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged "python-2.7", I think you should really be referencing the Python 2 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

Answer (score 4):

the problem is that methods with names starting with `__` like `__virt_method` have mangled names. basically their names are converted to `A__virt_method` or `B__virt_method` depending on the class they are in.

if you rename the method to `_virt_method` everything will work as expected

Answer (score 1):

If any variable starts with '__', python understands that this variable is actually a private variable so it uses a concept called `name mangling` to prevent direct access to the variable. If the variable starts with '_' its for internal use or restricted to local scope only(doesn't get load when `from something import *`).

```
In [60]: class A(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.__name = 'Premkumar'
    ...:     

In [61]: premkumar = A()

In [62]: premkumar.__dict__
Out[62]: {'_A__name': 'Premkumar'}
```

Comment: Name mangling applies to methods, but for variables the underscore notation is merely a convention and doesn't enforce the variable's privacy [source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#:~:text=%E2%80%9CPrivate%E2%80%9D%20instance%20variables%20that%20cannot%20be%20accessed%20except%20from%20inside%20an%20object%20don%E2%80%99t%20exist%20in%20Python.)

Comment: It is a convention for variables as well, from the source you have added
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables