# How to return a variable using another one Python

Tags: python, class, private, public

After working a lot with swift, I got used to the following syntax:

```
private var __privateVar = 100 // Not accessible from outside the Class
public var public_var: Int = {
    return __privateVar // Returns __privateVar, and is get-only variable
}
```

Is there a way to reproduce this in python 3?
Thanks a lot

Comment: [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: Still, is there a way to access those variables by returning them from another?

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's not entirely true with properties.

Comment: Does Python have “private” variables in classes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't even have the concept of access modifiers - so if you mean you want a private variable, that's not something you can do. You *can*, however, use a read-only property:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = 'some string'

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var
```

Then, use it as such:

```
obj = Test()
obj.var # works
obj.var = 'whatever' # raises AttributeError
obj._var = 'whatever' # still works
```

It's noteworthy that you *can* somewhat emulate the behavior of a private variable by prefixing your variable with a double underscore (such as in `__var`), which introduces name mangling if used in a class scope. This is not foolproof, though, and you can always get around it if you really want to. Generally, however, Python developers know not to assign to variables starting in one or two underscores.

Comment: To be clear, `_var` is _not_ read only and can still be viewed or modified by users.

Comment: @Alexanderthat should be clear enough from the very first sentence in the answer.