# Avoid calling method multiple times inside another method?

Tags: python

My problem simplified:

Let's assume that method_1 is a computationally heavy function. There's a possibility that it won't be necessary to call it at all when working with the instance of the class (so I don't want to put it in the inside the **init**-function). Then there is the other possibility that method_2 will be called multiple times and with my current solution in that case every time also the method_1 is called.

What would be easiest and most pythonic solution?

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.__x = x
      self.__y = y

   def method_1(self)
      # method that returns list which values vary depending on x and y
      return some_list


   def method_2(self, a)
      # method that modifies and returns specific list element from some_list according to a
      return do_modifications(self.method_1(), a)


   def method_3(self, arg1, ...)
      #some method
   ...
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the most pythonic but a possible solution is to save the list as a member of the class and then before method_2 calls method one it could check if the list already has a value, If its empty call method one if not use the saved list

Comment: Use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: As a side note, there is really no reason to be using double underscores in your attribute names here. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes) for more information on why this is not a good practice in Python.

Comment: Just like @TomKarzes mentioned the caching data that you will reuse would be the most pythoninc way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3.8, you can use [`functools.cache_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property):

> `@functools.cached_property(func)`
>
> Transform a method of a class into a property whose value is computed once and then cached as a normal attribute for the life of the instance. Similar to [property()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), with the addition of caching. Useful for expensive computed properties of instances that are otherwise effectively immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Make `method1`'s return value a property. (This is basically what `functools.cached_property` does; use that if possible.)

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self._m1_data = None

   def _method1(self):
       return some_list

   # Call _method1 on demand the first time you need
   # the result of self._method1(), and save the result for future
   # accesses
   @property
   def m1_data(self)
      if self._m1_data is None:
          self._m1_data = self._method1()
      return self._m1_data


   def method_2(self, a)
      return do_modifications(self.m1_data, a)
```