# How can I make some attributes not exposed in self-defined object? not using self.__name

Tags: python

For example, I have an instance:

```
class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, name, client=None):
        self.name = name
        self.client = client

job = Job('test')

job.client  # I don't want the client to be accessed outside, as it's only as an internal attribute.
```

from searching in the community, I didn't find a solution I want.

Although I knew that setting client as `__client` could achieve this, I don't want to change the attribute name.

I guess some magic functions are able to achieve this, like `__dict__` or `__getattr__`. can someone show me some idea? very appreciate.

Comment: You can use the @property decorator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes

Comment: Python does not have private variables. You can use a *single* underscore to denote that something is not part of the public API

Comment: @andrralv no, `property` doesn't really prevent anything from being accessible.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Yes, I know that way, but I prefer using magic function and I think Python can achieve it with magic function.

Comment: Why? Python *doesn't have private variables*. Why do you want to go against the conventional/recommended way? There is no way (other than by writing a C-extension) to make a variable inaccessible

Comment: alright, I think override `__getattr__` can do this, but it's in a hack way.

Comment: Overwriting `__getattr__` will only hide **one** way to access an attribute. It will not make it inaccessible.

Comment: @KlausD. yes, that's what I want. I want to hide it, the same effect as prefix `__` way.