# How do I make certain variables inaccessible when importing a program in Python?

Tags: python, import

For example:

```
import foo
...
```

In foo.py:

```
from bar import baz
def qux(x):
    ...
```

How do I make it so you can't do `from foo import baz` in the main file?

Comment: You may try to use @property. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052134/14772681) explained it and othe roptions very well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have “private” variables in classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes). To make this explicit: Try in *foo.py*: `from bar import baz as __baz` and replace `baz` with `__baz` elsewhere in that file where `baz` is referenced