# Name self is not defined, but I thought it was?

Tags: python, inheritance

I receive the error "NameError: name '_Activity__self' is not defined". I used self as a parameter in everything and for the members so I'm not sure what I'm missing. -- I'm trying to have Activity be the parent class and WakeUp be derived from Activity.

```
class Activity:

        def __init__ (self, d, t):
                __self.date = d
                __self.time = t

        def getDate(self):
                return self.date

        def getTime(self):
                return self.time


class WakeUp (Activity):

        def __init__ (self, d, t):
                Activity.__init__(self, d, t)
                __self.activityType = "WakeUp"

        def getType(self):
                return self.activityType
```

Comment: you should try `self.date = d`, same for time and activityType

Comment: Why are you using `__self` instead of `self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `__self` instead of `self`.
This should work
.

```
class Activity:

        def __init__ (self, d, t):
                self.date = d
                self.time = t

        def getDate(self):
                return self.date

        def getTime(self):
                return self.time


class WakeUp (Activity):

        def __init__ (self, d, t):
                Activity.__init__(self, d, t)
                self.activityType = "WakeUp"

        def getType(self):
                return self.activityType
```

Comment: but to make it a private  don't I have to put __ beforehand?

Comment: @mak95 that would be `self.__time`. I would recommend spending more time googling, because the private variable thing was there in the first search result.

Comment: @mak95 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes

Comment: okay thank you, I was following my professor's slides on python classes and he put the __ before self so I assumed that he was correct... learned not to trust my professor today!

Comment: @mak95 The first programing lesson ever should be how to use google.
Because it has more information than Stack Overflow does.
Moreover, the private variable solution itself is a SO question.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

`__self` would work if `__self` was in the tuple, eg `(__self, d, t)`. Note that the first parameter in the '**init**' tuple determines the 'self' name for the class. Convention recommends `self' but in fact it can be anything you want. It is the position in the parameters tht is important.

Check out 'What is self' in https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=self#what-is-self