# What is the name of those member function on classes?

Tags: python, class

This is my python code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, apple):
        self.apple = apple

    def set_apple_to(self, new_apple):
        self.apple = new_apple
```

I made function 'set_apple_to' becaues I think changing member variable directly could make hard to manage code and is dangerous. Now I am wondering what the name is that prevent changing member variable directly from external user.

Comment: Nothing prevents changing `<SomeClass instance>.apple` :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes

Comment: The concept of private/protected class attributes doesn't exist in Python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have “private” variables in classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes)

Comment: In python there is no need for getters and setters in a case like this. There might be cases when you use property or property and setter.

Comment: Although attributes can't be private (cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)), it can be useful to define **setters** to deal with maintaining state, or providing useful interfaces.