# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_overlapped'

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I am just trying to run a python file and this error shows up. I tried installing the 'trollius' package and the 'overlap' package if those are related to this error but none of them seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is about python access modifiers. You can try to remove underscore at the beginning. For further knowledge you may look at this link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes#:%7E:text=Python%20does%20not%20have%20any,expose%20your%20classes%20member%20variables.)