# Python - Returning multiple functions from closures

Tags: python

I'm trying to emulate private variables in Python by using function closures. My idea was to define a factory function that returns multiple getters. In Javascript, I would write the following:

```js
function Student(name, age) {
   let _name = name;
   let _age = age;

   return {
     getName() { return _name; },
     getAge() { return _age; }
   };
}

const john = Student("John", 22);

console.log(john.getName()); // prints John
console.log(john.getAge()); // prints 22
```

Is there any way to do the same in Python(i.e., returning multiple function objects from a closure)?

Comment: Have you tried `return lambda: _name, lambda: _age`?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641236/924827?

Comment: @MechanicPig: That gets the hiding/closure, but it doesn't make a virtual object with the functions as named "methods".

Comment: @MechanicPig Unfortunately, this approach returns a tuple, I need to be able to access these variables through the getters

Comment: @ShadowRanger Then use namedtuple `Student = namedtuple('Student', ['get_name', 'get_age'])` and `return Student(lambda: _name, lambda: _age)`

Comment: @MechanicPig: Well, it would have to have a different name from the function/pseudo-class (unless you redefine the `namedtuple` on each call, which is not a good idea), but yes, that works. My secondary, bad-idea solution was the more JS-like use of `types.SimpleNamespace` to get the same result without a named `tuple` subclass getting involved, but it's the same basic end result (`namedtuple` would be cheaper per-instance, at the expense of needing predefintion and being much more heavyweight for the class itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, one, this is horribly unPythonic, so I strongly recommend against it. Just use double underscore prefixed variables if you really need this, e.g.:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.__age

john = Student("John", 22)
print(john.name)
print(john.age)
john.name = "Steven"  # Dies; the property did not define a setter, so name is read-only
```

When prefixed with `__` (and not suffixed with any `_`), name-mangling prevents *accidental* use of private variables by the user, and any subclasses of the class in question (meaning a subclass could *also* define a `__name` instance attribute and it would be separate from the parent's definition, which gets the primary guarantee required of private variables). The `@property` decorated methods are the Pythonic way to make "interface read-only accessors to private/protected attributes" (they're read with `obj.name`/`obj.age`, but can't be assigned to since you didn't define an `setter`), and it's what you should be relying on.

If that's too verbose for you, `typing.NamedTuple` and `dataclasses.dataclass` are two nice options for making extremely low-boilerplate classes:

```
# Functional version (harder to add custom features to)
from collections import namedtuple

Student = namedtuple('Student', ('name', 'age'))

# Typed version (that's also easier to add features to)
from typing import NamedTuple

class Student(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    age: int
```

both of which are used the same as you used the original version, `john = Student("John", 22)`, and, being derived from `tuple`, are immutable (so you don't even need to bother making separate private attributes with public read-only accessors; the public attributes are already read-only).

Alternatively, with `dataclasses`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)  # Omit slots=True pre-3.10
class Student:
    __slots__ = 'name', 'age'  # Omit on 3.10+ where slots=True does the work for you
    name: str
    age: int
```

which again lets Python do the work for you (with `slots=True` or manually defined `__slots__`, the instances end up even more memory-efficient than `namedtuple`/`NamedTuple`, as they don't have to have a per-instance length, which inheriting from `tuple` requires).

Using any `namedtuple`/`NamedTuple`/`dataclass` solution adds the additional benefits of giving you useful definitions for a default `__repr__` (a more useful stringified form of an instance than the default "class name plus memory address"), equality comparison, and hashing (making instances legal members of a `dict`/`set`).

---

All that said, if you *must* do this terrible thing, the most direct equivalent would be:

```
import types

def Student(name, age):
    def getName():
        return name
    def getAge():
        return age
    # A simple dict wrapper that lets you use dotted attribute-style lookup instead
    # of dict-style bracketed lookup
    return types.SimpleNamespace(getName=getName, getAge=getAge)

# Even less Pythonic alternative using unnamed lambdas (so printing the methods
# themselves will tell you only that they are closures defined in Student
# but not the name of the methods themselves, in exchange for shorter code:
def Student(name, age):
    return types.SimpleNamespace(getName=lambda: name, getAge=lambda: age)


john = Student("John", 22)
print(john.getName())
print(john.getAge())
```

But to be clear, while it's more work to get at them (using the `inspect` module and the attributes it documents), those closure scoped variables are *still* accessible, they're not truly private. Python hides very little from users, following the "we're all adults here" principle; "privacy" is not intended as a security measure in any language, it's for interface definition and separation, and Python just drops the pretense.

Note that, [per PEP8, the functions *should* be named with `lowercase` or `lowercase_with_underscores` naming, not `mixedCase`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Python almost never uses `mixedCase` (and the few places they still do are deprecated and being removed; e.g. I believe `threading` removed the last of their `snakeCase` aliases in 3.10; classes are the only place they use `CapWords`, and otherwise everything is either fully upper or fully lower case). So if you're trying to make it even a *little* Pythonic, you'd use the names `get_name`/`get_age`, not `getName`/`getAge` (and as noted further up, in real Python code, you basically never see `get` prefixed methods at all, because using `property` removes the need for verb-names associated with methods, in favor of attribute-like access that keeps the plain noun-name).

Comment: The OOP approach looks cleaner indeed, but I have to stick to functional one. Thanks for both examples!

Answer (score 1):

According to your idea, it can be written as follows:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Student = namedtuple('Student', ['get_name', 'get_age'])
>>> def student(name, age):
...     return Student(lambda: name, lambda: age)
...
>>> i = student('hello', 19)
>>> i
Student(get_name=<function student.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001797FA62A70>, get_age=<function student.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001797FA62DD0>)
>>> i.get_name()
'hello'
>>> i.get_age()
19
```

Of course, this is not a popular way.

If you want to hide the actual tuple subclass, you can refer to the way of friend in the comment area.

Comment: To be clear, you don't even need to reassign the arguments; `name`/`age` could be used directly without bothering to alias them to `_name`/`_age`. Downside to using `namedtuple` is that each redefintion of the `namedtuple` consumes a KB or so of memory (usually okay, since it reduces the per-instance memory usage, but not so great when you make a new one for each instance).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, so I consider defining `Student` only once, but then I can't hide the actual subclass of tuple.

Comment: You can, but it's ugly in a different way: `def Student(name, age, *, _cls=namedtuple('Student', ['get_name', 'get_age'])): return _cls(lambda: name, lambda: age)`. You hide the definition of the `namedtuple` in the arguments (and make it a keyword-only argument, to prevent accidentally passing it, and prefixing the name with `_`, indicating it's not part of the public API so users shouldn't pass it themselves). Either that, or make another layer of wrapping, with a `make_Student` method that defines the `namedtuple` and `def Student`, returning `Student` that finds the class from closure. :-)

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's worth the bother here (the per-method closure scope itself adds non-trivial overhead, to the point where this will never be a cheap solution, memory-wise, thus why I stuck to `types.SimpleNamespace`, which avoids the need for a dedicated class at all), but I *do* like `namedtuple`, and will never say it's a bad idea (I did up-vote).

Answer (score -1):

The closure isn't necessary. Instead you can declare Student as a class.

You have used the correct convention (single underscore prefix) for the naming of the variables, and adding the getter functions is perfectly valid.