# Why does a library class break when I try to store and use an instance (delegation) instead of making a subclass (inheritance)?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm making a game using the `turtle` standard library module for graphics. I have working code that creates a subclass of `Turtle`, like so:

```
import random

class Food(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # more code...
```

However, I wanted to see if I could make it work without using inheritance instead. This is my attempt:

```
from turtle import Turtle
from random import randint

class Food():
    def __init__(self):
        self.food = Turtle()
        # more code, but now modifying `self.food` instead of `self`
```

Elsewhere in the program, I have an instance `food` of the `Food` class, an I try to do collision detection between the `food` and another Turtle, `snake.head`:

```
if snake.head.distance(food) < 15:
    ...
```

In the original code, it works fine, but with the new version I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Various stuff beginning\Snake_retry\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    if snake.head.distance(food) < 15:
  File "C:\Users\palliativo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 1858, in distance
    return abs(pos - self._position)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pos' referenced before assignment
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general: when using *composition instead of inheritance* (what the second attempt does), it is necessary to *delegate* everything that needs to use the internal object - *including* any calls to library code. Using composition instead of inheritance entails *not using inheritance*; therefore, the class is no longer a subtype of whatever library class; therefore, other code *can't use it* [the same way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

---

When the `.distance` method is called on the `snake.head`, the Turtle class needs to be given something whose position it knows how to find. It has the following rules ([quoting from the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/turtle.py#L1851)):

```
if y is not None:
    pos = Vec2D(x, y)
if isinstance(x, Vec2D):
    pos = x
elif isinstance(x, tuple):
    pos = Vec2D(*x)
elif isinstance(x, TNavigator):
    pos = x._position
```

(This is slightly offset from the error message reported, because of changes between Python versions.)

In other words, it knows how to use:

- two separate integers `x` and `y` (i.e., directly telling it the position);
- a `Vec2D` (directly telling it the position, but using the class that the library provides for representing positions);
- a tuple (directly telling it the position, but using values stored in a tuple);
- a `TNavigator` (in practice, this means a Turtle, but there are other possibilities).

When `Food` inherits from `Turtle`, it's a `Turtle`. It has built-in position tracking, which other `Turtle`s can use: accessing the hidden `._position` attribute. (The leading underscore means that other classes aren't supposed to know about it or use it; but [Python does not have true privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219).)

When `Food` *stores* a `Turtle`, it *isn't* a `Turtle`. While the logic is obvious to the programmer - fetch the turtle stored in the `.food` attribute, and then get the position of *that* - the already-written `Turtle` code has no way to know that.

To fix the problem, we can extract the underlying `Turtle` at the point where the method is called:

```
if snake.head.distance(food.food) < 15:
    ...
```

Or we can implement the interface that the library code wants to use. In this specific instance, that won't be feasible; it's explicitly checking for types, so we'd need the class to be one of those types - in which case, we might as well just use inheritance in the first place.

But consider another example, where someone else has written a distance *function* (not method) that expects two Turtles:

```
def public_distance(t1, t2):
    # this version uses the interface that the Turtle class provides
    # for other code to get the position: calling the `pos` method
    return abs(t1.pos() - t2.pos())

def private_distance(t1, t2):
    # this version directly (naughtily) accesses the "private" attribute
    return abs(t1._position - t2._position)
```

Then we could adapt the class to meet that interface. For a missing method, implement the method, and have its logic check the wrapped object. For a missing attribute, [use a (read-only) *property*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160) that checks for the corresponding information in the wrapped object. Here's an example showing both (and using the property to implement the method):

```
class Food:
    # other stuff as before...

    @property
    def _position(self):
        return self.food._position

    def pos(self):
        return self._position
```

(One might ask, why does the Turtle class use a method `pos`, instead of a `property`? That's because it's old code following an old design, before `property` support was added to Python. Updating things like this is low priority for the Python dev team; it risks breaking old code; and it involves writing new documentation - and hoping that tutorial authors get the hint as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to do

```py
if snake.head.distance(food.food) < 15:
    food.generate_food()
```