# Accessing private nested class

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I made this simple class, which still is playing with my mind:

```
class A {
private:
    class B {};

public:
    B getB() {
        return B();
    };
};
```

As of C++03, this class compiles fine, but there is just no *nice looking way* to assign the result of `getB()` to an lvalue, in the sense that:

```
A::B b = A().getB();
```

Does not compile.

I got it by using an intermediate template, in this fashion:

```
template <typename T>
struct HideType {
    typedef T type;
};

HideType<A::B>::type b = A().getB();
```

But this looks just terrible, for this simple task of getting an A::B lvalue variable.

This is not true anymore as of C++11, or at least it is not with gcc. This code is still not valid:

```
A::B b = A().getB();
```

But this **is** valid:

```
auto b = A().getB();
```

Is there a loophole in the standard respect to this?

Comment: Relevant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type

Comment: I cannot get [`HideType<A::B>::type b = ...`](http://ideone.com/jwsXhG) to compile, could you show a MCVE where it happens? You might be interested in litb's [robber structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110526/allowing-access-to-private-members) for an alternative.

Answer (score 11):

From Standard, Clause 11 (Member access control):

> A member of a class can be
>   — private; that is, its **name** can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.
>   — protected; that is, its **name** can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is
>   declared, by classes derived from that class, and by their friends (see 11.4).
>   — public; that is, its **name** can be used anywhere without access restriction.

So access control is applied to **names**.

In

```
auto b = A().getB();
```

you don't use private names, therefore it's legal, according to Standard

Answer (score 1):

The fact why `A::B b =  A().getB()` doesn't work is because `B` is a private class member of `A`. If you make it public then your code will compile. It works with `auto` because `auto` just checks the type of the object assigned to it without needing to call the constructor of the object (just like `declval`). So it assigns `b` with the return type of `getB` present in class `A`. You can change your code in the following way too :

```
decltype( declval<A>().getB() ) b = A().getB();
```

( If `declval` is new to you then I must tell you that it would return an rvalue of the return type of the function (here `getB` whose return type is `B`) of a class (here `A`) without calling the constructor of the class ! (This should however be used with functions like `decltype` and `sizeof` only.) So it prevents the overhead of creating a class object and then using its function. )

Now according to me, I don't think this is a loophole in the standard rather I feel the loophole has been removed ! It's obvious from your own code, see the function `getB`. How difficult it is to instantiate an object of `B` because it's defined in private ! In such a case working with `B` becomes difficult. The idea behind this is that the name of the type (ie `B`) in the class `A` is inaccessible but the type is still usable which is why you can get an object of `B`. You can understand the use of `auto` if you understand the this template code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>  // for std::is_same
using namespace std;
class A
{
    class B
    {};
    public:
    B getB()
    {
        return B();
    }
};
template<typename T>
void check (T b)
{
    cout<<boolalpha;
    is_same<decltype( declval<A>().getB() ), T> x;  // checks if T & B are of same type
    cout<<x.value<<'\n';
}
int main()
{
    A obj;
    check (obj.getB());
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
true
```

As the `template` could identify `B`, hence `auto` too identifies `B`.

Comment: "*It works with `auto` because that's what `auto` is !!!! It will just check if the type assigned to it is valid or not*" This is all gibberish.

Comment: And `decltype` is C++11, just like `auto`, so what's the point in recommending it?

Comment: Thats just an extra info to tell the OP that you can access object of `B` without even using `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there was such a defect in a draft of the Standard, but it had been corrected by [WP 1170](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1170).

Probably, there is a compiler bug. The declaration `auto b = A().getB();` involves template argument deduction for the `auto` *type-specifier*, so according to the C++11 Standard it should be ill-formed, because that type deduction fails.