# How to specialize a template sub-class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize a template class inside another class but the compiler won't let me. The code works outside of class Foo but not inside and I want struct Bla to be private to class Foo.

```
class Foo {
   template<typename ... Ts> struct Bla; 
   template<> struct Bla<> { static constexpr int x = 1; };
};

error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Foo'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specialize inside the class, use:

```
class Foo {
public: // so we can test it easily
   template<typename ... Ts> struct Bla; 
};

// specialize it outside the class
template<> class Foo::Bla<> { static constexpr int x = 1; }; 

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo::Bla<>::x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the solution.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow note that I used `public` here, so I can display `Bla::x`. However I guess you are using a `friend` or displaying via a member function, in which case you should be ok.

Comment: This makes me think though. Doesn't that allow violating the privacy of a class? `class Foo { static constexpr int y = 1; public: template<typename ... Ts> struct Bla; }; template<> struct Foo::Bla<> { static constexpr int x = y; };` Foo::y is private but by specializing Bla any user of Foo can gain access to it through Bla::x.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow my answer is too long to post here. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/q/424104/3093378 and search for "backdoor"

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow and that's probably exactly what you meant: http://ideone.com/dBV0eU

Answer (score 4):

You simply cannot do that. The error sums it up nicely. Class templates can only be specialized in namespace scope. `class Foo` is not a namespace.

You can do it external to the class, as per this example from the standard [temp.class.spec]:

> A class template partial specialization may be declared or redeclared in any namespace scope in which its
>   definition may be defined (14.5.1 and 14.5.2). [ Example:
>
> ```
>  template<class T> struct A {  
>      struct C {
>          template<class T2> struct B { };
>      };
>  };
>
>  // partial specialization of A<T>::C::B<T2>
>  template<class T> template<class T2>
>    struct A<T>::C::B<T2*> { };
>
> A<short>::C::B<int*> absip; // uses partial specialization
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Comment: upvoted for the standard quotes, you are really fast :)

Comment: @vsoftco Just start at chapter Templates and keep searching for "scope" :)

Comment: yeah I know how it works, but still, I was too lazy :)