# Access to private member variables/functions of a C++ class in Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

Say I have a class Foo:

```
class Foo {
private:
    std::string bar;
public:
    Foo () {}
    Foo (const std::string& bar_) { this->bar = bar_; }
    std::string get_bar () { return this->bar; }
};
```

and a Foo python wrapper FooWrapper.pyx:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "Foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo ()
        Foo (string)
```

Is it possible to access `std::string bar` in the .pyx file, without modifying Foo?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't access a private member in C++, then you can't access it in Cython as well.

You could try a trick like this that overwrites the "private" keyword: https://stackoverflow.com/a/424125