# Why does a hole for access checking exist for explicit template instantiations?

Tags: c++, templates

[temp.explicit] contains this wording:

> The usual access checking rules do not apply to names used to specify explicit instantiations. *[Note:* In
>   particular, the template arguments and names used in the function declarator (including parameter types,
>   return types and exception specifications) may be private types or objects which would normally not be
>   accessible and the template may be a member template or member function which would not normally be
>   accessible. *—end note ]*

Why are those rules disabled specifically for this case? In the extreme, this allows for [arbitrary access of any private member of any class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173080/2069064) in a well-defined way ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6281562bf1aac906) - zero warnings):

> ```
> struct A {
> private:
>   int member;
> };
>
> template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
> struct Rob { 
>   friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
>     return M;
>   }
> };
>
> // tag used to access A::member
> struct A_member { 
>   typedef int A::*type;
>   friend type get(A_member);
> };
>
> template struct Rob<A_member, &A::member>;
>
> int main() {
>   A a;
>   a.*get(A_member()) = 42; // write 42 to it
>   std::cout << "proof: " << a.*get(A_member()) << std::endl;
> }
> ```

So that's the downside of this rule. What's the upside? Why do we need this hole to avoid access checking?

Comment: Re: "arbitrary access" -- so what? The type system protects against mistake, not fraud.

Comment: C++' s access checking protects against Murphy, not Machiavelli. You can access a protected or private member in other ways (pointer shenanigans, mostly). So yeah.

Comment: It is an old and boring topic!

Comment: @Xeo Sure, but presumably if we're giving Machiavelli all this power, we're doing it because it offers some other benefits. I'd like to know what those benefits are.

Comment: There might be legitimate reasons for you, as the author of the class, to specialise something. And as specialisations can only happen at namespace scope...

Comment: @xeo add an example and that is an answer!

Comment: @Yakk: Feel free to do so. I don't have a proper example at hand and am otherwise preoccupied right now. :)

Answer (score 4):

This question is covered by Herb Sutter's [GotW #76](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm). Member functions are expected to be able to access private members of a class. When member function is a template, you would expect to be able to specialize such template. This is a conflict between the C++ access control model and the template model, which could be avoided by complicating (already complex) C++ standard. While it is possible to bypass C++ access controls and access private members in this way, you are strongly advised against doing that.

*Note: @Xeo already explained most of these points in his comments above.*