# What's the difference between a private variable in Java and a private variable in a C++ struct?

Tags: java, c++, class, variables, struct

What's the difference between a private variable in a Java class and a private variable in a C++ structure?

Java code for example see below : implementing an ADT table.
c++ example see below : applying "hiding the implementation"

I looked online couldn't find any helpful source related to this particular topic

Java example:

```
class Table{
    private int size;
    private int num;//numbers of items are stored in the arrray
    private int[] array;

    public Table(int size, int[] array){
        this.size = size;
        this.array = new int[size];
    }

    public insert(int[] array, int newItem){
        if(num<size){
            //for loop for adding items into the array;
        }
        else if(num>=size){
            //increment the size and copy the original array to the new array
        }
    }
}
```

C++ example of implementation hiding:

```
struct B{
private:
    char j;
    float f;

public:
    int i;
    void func();
};


void::func(){
    i = 0;
    j = '0';
    f = 0.0;
};

int main(){
    B b;
    b.i = i; // legal
    b.j = '1'; // illegal
    b.f = 1.0; // illegal now

}
```

in c++ we cant change the private variable, is it because these b.j = '1'; b.f = 1.0; two lines are in the main() function thats why? in java we cant change the private variables in main() neither.

thank you!

Answer (score 5):

With very few exceptions, private variables in C++ and Java work similarly. Specifically, *in general*, those variables can only be accessed by member functions of the class or `struct` containing those variables. Access to those fields / data members is otherwise disallowed.

There are a couple of exceptions to this rule. A non-exhaustive list:

- In Java, you can use reflection to make private fields of other classes accessible, though doing so may be prevented by the access controller.
- In C++, private fields may be accessed by classes and functions that are marked as `friend`s of the class containing the private field.

Comment: FWIW, the language lets anyone access private data in c++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173080/4342498

Comment: so we can't access private variables in the main() in c++ eh?

Comment: @NathanOliver C++’s access control system was, I believe, designed to guard against accidental error rather than deliberate subversion, so that doesn’t surprise me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Private variables are variables that are NOT accessible outside of the class itself.

Learn more about access modifiers [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/)

C++ `private` in `structs` are similar, in the way that they can only be accessed in the struct's `member methods`.

Comment: so we can't access private variables in the main() in c++ eh?

Comment: No. It is why access modifiers exist in the first place.

Comment: You can't ACCIDENTALLY access `private` variables in `main`, but if you go out of your way to access them, there are a number of ways to do it that do not even need to delve into abusing Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, the answer should be "You cannot hide any data in structs, because memory pointers exist"