# What's the best practice to check target object's private variable in unit test code using gtest framework?

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm using gtest as my unit test framework. In my work, it's a common case that a public method modifies some private variables in the object. These variables stores the "states" of the object and has affects to the object's behavior. For example:

```
class ConferenceRoom {
public:
  void AddUser(const std::string& user_info);

  void OnDataReceived(uint32_t user_id, const std::string& message);

private:
  // Map[user_id] --> User
  std::unordered_map<uint32_t, User> user_map_;
};
```

I want to test the public method `AddUser` with various good/bad user_info, but I can't access the private variable `user_map_` directly to check if this map is changed as I expected. I don't know what's the best practice for this case? I know some solutions:

1. Using `friend` to access ConferenceRoom's private variable, this will make ConferenceRoom aware test code.
2. Declare `user_map_` as protected, and using TestRoom inherits ConferenceRoom, then check the map in TestRoom.
3. Add a virtual private method `const std::unordered_map<uint32_t, User>& GetUserMap() const`; using TestRoom inherits ConferenceRoom and overrides this virtual method, then access private `user_map_` with `GetUserMap`.

I'm sure there must be some other solutions for this case. In my mind, the solution should be isolate class `ConferenceRoom` with test code, and the class ConferenceRoom can be delivered to use clearly without any strange code. What your best practice?

Comment: If accessing private variable is the motive, then it's a possible duplicate of [Can I access private members from outside the class without using friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/424104/514235)?

Comment: @iammilind, thanks for your information. I think that post is discussing  another different topic.

Comment: Private data should be a implementation detail. Can't you test the public interface?

Comment: yes, I want to test the **public** interface `AddUser()`, but I don't know how to check whether `AddUser()` works as design if I can't access the private variable `user_map_`. And no other objects in the system needs to access `user_map_` except the unit test code, so I think I should not add a public access method such as `UesrMap()` @Jarod42

Comment: You don't. That's testing the implementation. You should be testing the behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Using a small template magic code as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416529/514235) already, you may access the private variables directly without modifying the source.

For your code, you have to do following:

```
ALLOW_ACCESS(ConferenceRoom, user_map_, std::unordered_map<uint32_t, User>); // setup
// ... class declarations ...
ConferenceRoom object;
auto& user_map_ = ACCESS(object, user_map_);
// use `user_map_`
```

#### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24e9f2dffcd1eb17).