# How to access private class members with out being in the in class

Tags: c++

I want to change the data in the private members but the delete_Data() function is outside the class so  how to get the members without being declared in the class and erase them using the delete_Data() function
the only way it works for me it to declare delete_data()function in the class on public section but
our teachers said you should only use this method
i need help pls thank you
for eg

Enter your Name: John
Enter your id: 1234

Name: John
ID:1234

Name :
ID:0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class data{
  private:
     string name;
     int id;
  public:
     void add_Data()
{
     cout<<"Enter you Name :";
     cin>>name;
     cout<<"Enter your id :";
     cin>>id;
}
    void display_Data(){
     cout<<"Name :"<<name<<endl;
     cout<<"ID :"<<id<<endl;
}
};

void delete_Data(){
     name="";
     id=0;
}
  int main(){
    data one;
    one.add_Data();
    one.display_Data();
    delete_Data()
    one.display_Data;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could declare `delete_Data` as a friend function, but I don't see why you wouldn't have delete data inside the class. Also `name`, and `id` doesn't make sense outside the class. You should either have `delete_Data(data&)` or `delete_Data(data*)`.

Comment: Why don't you ask your teacher? Isn't that their job? Asking random people on the internet to guess what your teacher wanted seems like a bad idea.

Comment: This is quite a common interview question: not only in C++ but also in C#.  There are some answers in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-access-private-data-members-class-without-using-member-friend-function/

Comment: I tried but I don't get a solution that's why I asked in Stackoverflow the only method it worked for me is to declare delete function inside public class

Comment: @cup A site that uses `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in their examples should not be trusted to give good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually<sup>**✝**</sup>, the member functions and the `friend`s of the class can access the private members of a class, via an instance of the class.

Therefore, in your case, make the `delete_Data` function as `friend` function.

```
class data 
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int id;
public:
    // ...
    friend void delete_Data(data& obj);
};

void delete_Data(data& obj)
{
    obj.name = "";
    obj.id = 0;
}
```

Now in the `main()`

```
data one;
delete_Data(one);
```

Also note that, you need to pass an instance of the `data` class to access the members of the class.

---

**Side notes**:

- <sup>**✝**</sup>There are other tricky ways, by which we can also
  access the member. However, the whole point of the
  `public`/`protected`/`private` modifiers, is not to do that.

  See more:
  [Can I access private members from outside the class without using friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424104/can-i-access-private-members-from-outside-the-class-without-using-friends)
- Also see
  [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: "*Only the member functions and the `friend`s of the class can access the private members of a class.*" - actually, that is not true. There is another way, using some [template trickery](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html).

Comment: another easy way is to just use pointers and offsets.